# Creating Sentinel-2 NDVI time series chart in Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

What is the equivalent of the following syntax in Python:

```
ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear({
               imageCollection: collection, 
               bandName: 'NDVI', 
               region: forest, 
               regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
               scale: 500});
```

Comment: You can extract the data and use `matplotlib` in colab to create the plot. I don't think you can call the `ui` methods from Colab

Comment: that is what I figured. It seems (to me) such a thing does not exist in Python (yet.)

Comment: @NoLie well, yes. There's the [GEE Python API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install) which you can easily use to extract the data from GEE - and subsequently use ordinary `matplolib` functionality to create any plot you want.